# Call methods of a collection of interfaces with a single call

Tags: c#, class, dynamic, interface

So I have the following:

```
public interface Client
{
    void Operation1();
    void Operation2();
}

public class Client1 : Client
{
    public void Operation1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client1 - Operation1");
    }

    public void Operation2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client1 - Operation2");
    }
}

public class Client2 : Client
{
    public void Operation1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client2 - Operation1");
    }

    public void Operation2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client2 - Operation2");
    }
}

public class Client3 : Client
{
    public void Operation1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client3 - Operation1");
    }

    public void Operation2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client3 - Operation2");
    }
}
```

I need a way to call a method of all the clients with a single call. Something like a delegate.

Basically I want to do the following:
    Clients.Operation1()
Which outputs:
    Client1 - Operation1
    Client2 - Operation1
    Client3 - Operation1

One way to achieve this is to have the following class:

```
public class Clients : Client
{
    public List<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public void Operation1()
    {
        foreach(Client c in Clients)
        {
            c.Operation1();
        }
    }
    public void Operation2()
    {
        foreach (Client c in Clients)
        {
            c.Operation2();
        }
    }
}
```

but then whenever I change the Client interface, I will also have to change the Clients class.
Is there some way to generate the Clients class(or something similar) dynamically?

Please let me know if you need a better explanation, because it is really hard for me to explain this question.

Comment: I do get it. It seems what you have is fine, and there's a name for it [Composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). When you're modifying the other client classes, why can't you spend very little time in adding one method in Clients class?

Comment: Generally the interface ensures that your code will not change. To solve this you can have one method, that takes and `Func` argument with the method that you want to call and you won't have to implement the `Client` interface in `Clients` class

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Because I am really stubborn and I wouldn't learn anything if I just took the time to add a method in that class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply implement one method `Execute` and pass the method that you want execute to it:

```
public class Clients
{
    public List<Client> ClientList { get; set; }

    public void Execute(Action<Client> action)
    {
        ClientList.ForEach(action);
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
new Clients().Execute(x => x.Operation1(someString, someInt));
new Clients().Execute(x => x.Operation2());
```

With this example you will not have to implement the interface in your `Clients` class and will not have to remaster it every time the interface changes.

Comment: Another problem though: what do I do with the arguments? Some of the methods do take arguments. For example Operation1 might take a string while Operation2 has no arguments. How would I pass those accordingly?

Comment: You will just pass the arguments in the calling function, I've updated the answer

Comment: Just don't forget to be careful with the arguments, as you're taking them into the `clojure`, so I advice you read a bit on this subject